# NodeJs: Including a third party js library as a regular file vs. listing as a local dependency on package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

We need to include a third party `js` library that isn't available as `npm` module. (don't want to focus the attention in the library itself so let's call it "third-party-library").

We:

- clone locally the repository
- build following their documentation `dist/third-party-library.compiled.js`
- need to include this `compiled.js` into our project.

While this approach **does** work:

***our-main-index.js***

```js
import foo from './vendor/third-party-library.compiled.js'

foo.goo(); // works
```

I was trying to list this dependency in our `package.json` as following:

```json
dependencies: {
  "third-party-library": "file:./vendor/third-party-library",
  ...
}
```

then, create this structure:

```bash
|-- package.json
|-- vendor
    |-- third-party-library
         |-- package.json                      # create this file
         |-- third-party-library.compiled.js   # move this file here
```

***vendor/third-party-library/package.json***

```json
{
  "name": "third-party-library",
  "main": "./shaka-player.compiled.js",
}
```

So we were able to consider this `.compiled.js` as any other dependency:

```bash
npm i
```

```js
import foo from 'third-party-library'

foo.goo(); // DOES NOT WORK
```

But this second approach raises this traces from the library itself:

```bash
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/soruce-map-loader/dist/cjs.js): 
Failed to source map from '.../vendor/third-party-library/disc/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/js/es6/object/values.js' 
file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, '.../third-party-library/......'
```

Despite being a warning, the thing doesn't work.

Why doesn't this errors related to finding their dependencies raise if I import the file directly but happen when trying to list as a dependency?

---

== EDIT ==

---

Adding additional info. Summary:

**Using the very same file `third-party-library.compiled.js`**

When used as:

```js
import foo from './as-local-file/third-party-library.compiled.js'

console.log(Object.keys(foo)) // Array(13) [ ... ]
```

but trying to use it as a dependency:

```js
import foo from 'third-party-library';

console.log(Object.keys(foo)) // export 'default' was not found in 'third-party-library' (module has no exports)
```

```js
import * as foo from 'third-party-library';

console.log(Object.keys(foo)) // []
```